# How do I know pressure is equal in a static fluid in connected tubes?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

[image]

This is from knight.

What I don't get is why $p_1=p_2$. I don't think we can use the hydro static pressure formula because the top and bottom of a cone are not identical. I get why pressure at the top and bottom must be equal, but why can't the pressure at the middle be different?

Thank you

Comment: Experimental evidence has shown that p1=p2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Water pressure increases with depth not width. Since p1 and p2 are at the same depth and have the same atmospheric pressure above, p1=p2. Water pressure increases about 1.47 pounds per square inch for each meter of depth no matter what the size or shape of the container, as long as the container is not so narrow that the capillary effect occurs.